# Modify rewrite rule to handle four ids rather than just one

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, clean-urls

I  have rewrite rule which gives id from link to script and it works perfectly:

```
RewriteRule ^index/viewproduct/id/(\d+)$ produkty/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

I need one more RewriteRule to handle URLS like:
in link like:

```
/index/viewproduct/id/ID1/subcategoryId/ID2/idCat/ID3/type/ID4
```

I want to rewrite all of it (any ID1,ID2,ID3,ID4 which are different) to script (one file like above and give **ID1** to this script)

second option: If someone accessed a URL like this:

```
/index/viewproduct/id/ID1/subcategoryId/ID2/idCat/ID3/type/ID4
```

it should be redirected to script what is works above `(RewriteRule ^index/viewproduct/id/(\d+)$ produkty/index.php?id=$1 [L])`

any ideas ?

Comment: Ok "mission complete" by:RewriteRule ^index/viewproduct/id/(\d+)/(.+) produkty/index.php?id=$1 [L]

Comment: "mission complete"? That directive is rather "general" and doesn't exactly do what you stated in the question? What do you mean by the "second option"? Is that an _alternative_ to the first option?

Comment: Yea alternative. Not exactly but do the job and works :)

Comment: Of course i can fight still and rewrite only these ID's (ID2,ID3,ID4) but i have no idea how to do it. Anyway redirect all structure below is fine in my case.

Comment: If that is acceptable to you then you should add that as an answer (and later accept it). However, for such a generalised solution, you could have simply removed the trailing `$` on the original directive to handle both URLs?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you posted an answer in the comments.